# Issue storing raw pointers in boost R-tree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am getting compile errors when trying to remove a value from an r-tree. I also store a raw pointer together with the box, which seems to be causing the problem - I do not get error if I store int, string or a shared_ptr.

I do not have the option to switch to shared_ptr because all these come from a legacy library. Is there another workaround?

I have the tree defined as follows:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
namespace bgm = boost::geometry::model;

typedef boost::geometry::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point_t;
typedef boost::geometry::model::box<point_t> box_t;
typedef std::pair<box_t, Data*> value_t;

boost::geometry::index::rtree<value_t, boost::geometry::index::quadratic<16>> rtree;
```

And the code that fails is as follows:

```
while(!rtree.empty()) {
   auto it = rtree.begin();
   auto value = *it;
   rtree.remove(value); // <-- this is where the error appears.
}
```

And the errors is as follows:

```
...../boost/geometry/index/equal_to.hpp:127:60: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for 'struct boost::geometry::index::detail::equals<NdsInstance*, void>'
         && detail::equals<T2>::apply(l.second, r.second);
                                                        ^
...../boost/geometry/index/equal_to.hpp:28:8: error: candidates are: struct boost::geometry::index::detail::equals<Geometry*, Tag>
struct equals<Geometry *, Tag>
       ^
...../boost/geometry/index/equal_to.hpp:37:8: error:                 struct boost::geometry::index::detail::equals<T, void>
struct equals<T, void> 
       ^
...../boost/geometry/index/equal_to.hpp:127:60: error: incomplete type 'boost::geometry::index::detail::equals<NdsInstance*, void>' used in nested name specifier
         && detail::equals<T2>::apply(l.second, r.second);
                                                        ^
```

Full code sample can be found on [Colliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8f3855f7961b011). I am using gcc 4.9.3 and boost 1.62 (same error with boost 1.61).

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue and I find another way to walk around:

redefine an equal_to functor (fourth template argument of rtree)

example code:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
namespace bgm = boost::geometry::model;

using point = bgm::point<double, 2, bg::cs::spherical_equatorial<bg::degree>>;
using value_type = std::pair<point, int*>;

struct my_equal { 
    using result_type = bool; 
    bool operator() (value_type const& v1, value_type const& v2) const { 
        return bg::equals(v1.first, v2.first) && v1.second == v2.second;} 
}; 

using rtree = bgi::rtree<value_type, bgi::quadratic<16>, bgi::indexable<value_type>, my_equal>;

int main() {
    int a,b;
    rtree rtree;
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(45,45), &a));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(45,45), &b));
    rtree.remove(std::make_pair(point(45,45), &b));

    return 0;
}
```

working on gcc 6.2.1, boost 1.61.0 (also on gcc 4.9.3 and boost 1.58.0)

inspired from [this ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10861)

Comment: I like your solution better than mine, it makes it a lot cleaner to access back the data.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a wrapper for the raw pointer:

```
struct wrapData {
    public:
    wrapData(Data *data) { _data = data; }
    operator Data*() const { return _data; }
    private:
    Data *_data;
};

typedef std::pair<box_t, wrapData> value_t;
```